# Stopping delphi program in an infinite loop

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe3

When an indefinite loop occurs in Delphi, the debugger will not even give me a stack trace when I hit the stop button.  If I have a suspicion of where the program is stalling, I can put a breakpoint and it will stop if that is the correct indefinite loop.

Here is a sample program to deliberately cause an indefinite loop:

```
procedure TForm1.btnDebugInfiniteLoopClick(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
    I:=0;
    while I<100 do begin
        I:=1+1;
        if I>64 then I:=I div 2;
    end;
end;
```

When stopped, I get something that looks like:

```
ntdll.RtlUserThreadStart:
776301B4 89442404         mov [esp+$04],eax
776301B8 895C2408         mov [esp+$08],ebx
776301BC E9E99C0200       jmp $77659eaa
776301C1 8DA42400000000   lea esp,[esp+$0000]
776301C8 8DA42400000000   lea esp,[esp+$0000]
776301CF 90               nop 
ntdll.KiFastSystemCall:
776301D0 8BD4             mov edx,esp

...
```

As I single step (F7), it single steps a few lines, then locks up until I hit break again, at which point I get the same result.

Comment: You don't indicate which version of Delphi you're using in this or your previous question. Since this may be version specific, you may want to add a tag that indicates that version as well as general `delphi`.

Comment: Delphi XE3 is the version begin used.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the suspect loop, you will see if program execution halts there.

Comment: When you start single-stepping, are you sure you're stepping in the right thread? Delphi doesn't know which thread you want, so it just picks one. Make sure you select the main thread, and *then* check the call stack.

Comment: Thanks, Rob!  That helped a lot.  I didn't realize I could get a call stack this way.

Comment: By the way, what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to get the debugger to show me where the program stalled at.  For some reason, even though I am only using one thread, there are four threads in the debugger.  Rob Kennedy answered my question by pointing out that I must choose the correct thread and then I can see where the program stalled.  What was happening is I was trying to single step in assembly hoping to get to my source but I was in the wrong thread (and one I never created).

Comment: similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066834/program-freezes-but-the-cpu-utulization-is-zero

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered in comments by Rob Kennedy.  I must open a thread view from debug window to get a list of threads and choose the correct thread; at that point I can see where my program is indefinitely looping.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative answer: considering you're using Delphi XE3, it comes bundled with the profiler: AQTime which will find things like this real real fast.